# Displaying content in a view

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I am a newbie to iPhone App development.

I want to have a view, which displays some images and text. All static content. How do i have a vertical scrolling option so that user can scroll and see the contents?
How can i use interface builder to scroll up and add content ?

Can you provide some tutorial on how to do it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a UIScrollView, then place UILabels for text and UIImages for pictures inside. Scrolling will be more or less automatic.